# Trying to upload more than one file gets an error Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have the following request:
[image]

this will return the following error:
[image]

but, if i remove the second file, leaving only one file, the request performs ok

please advice.

Answer (score -1):

My expectation that this is due to missing `Parameter Name` value as it correlates with `Name is blank` error.

Can you try the following:

1. [Copy files you want to upload to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](http://Recording%20File%20Uploads%20with%20JMeter)
2. [Record your file upload event using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
3. Compare recorded script with the one you are currently have.

---

Another assumption is that your endpoint doesn't support multiple file uploads so you will have to either to it sequentially or use multiple threads and [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) to do it at the same moment but using different threads (virtual users)

Comment: Is not due to missing Parameter Name value since i did not checked the "use multipart/form-data for post" check box. As I said above, this work fine for one file, and gives the error for more than one file.